# XUL MenuItem disappearing after popup is added dynamically

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am trying to add submenus to a dynamically built popup menu that appears when your right click anywhere in the browser window. The first level is built fine, but when I try to add a popup to those entries, the menu items disappear.

this is the object i'm building from:

```
var snpshot = {
    'Head':'', 
    'Subhead':'',
    'Date':'',
    'Url':'',
};
```

This is the code stored in my onLoad event so the menu is built when the browser starts:

**the part that doesn't seem to work is rclickItem.appendChild(mPopup)** -- it is doing 'something' but the menu entries the popup is added to go blank and shrink, though rolling the cursor over it seems to suggest that they are still there.

```
  onLoad: function() {
    var mainPop = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS, "menupopup");
    mainPop.setAttribute('id', 'rclickMenu_MenuPopupContainer');

    //attach it to main rclick object
    var mainRclick = document.getElementById("rclickMenu_Main");
    mainRclick.appendChild(mainPop);

    mainOverlay.createMainRclick(); //THIS WORKS
    //add popups -- AS SOON AS THE POPUPS ARE ADDED THE ENTRIES DISAPPEAR!
    mainOverlay.createPopUpMenus();
},

createMenuItem: function(lblToUse){
    //create the XUL menuitem
    var itemToAdd = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS, "menuitem");
    itemToAdd.setAttribute('label',lblToUse);
    itemToAdd.setAttribute('id','rclickMenu_'+lblToUse);
    return itemToAdd;
},

createMenuPopup: function(idToUse){
    var mPopup = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS, "menupopup");
    mPopup.setAttribute('id','rclickMenuPopup_' + idToUse );
    return mPopup;
},

createMainRclick: function(){
    for (var property in snpshot){
        var mItem = mainOverlay.createMenuItem( property );
        var mainPop = document.getElementById("rclickMenu_MenuPopupContainer");
        mainPop.appendChild(mItem);
    }
},

createPopUpMenus: function(){
    for (var property in snpshot){
        var mPopup = mainOverlay.createMenuPopup( property );

        var rclickItem = document.getElementById("rclickMenu_"+property);
        rclickItem.appendChild(mPopup);
    }
},
```

And the XUL (this is the main popup that comes up when you right click, with my menu item added (which I dynamically add to in the js)

```
<menupopup id="contentAreaContextMenu">

    <menu 
     id="rclickMenu_Main" 
     label="Main Section">
    </menu>

</menupopup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`<menupopup>` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menupopup):

> It may be placed inside a `menu`, `menulist`, `toolbarbutton`, or a `button`

Note that `<menuitem>` tag is not on that list. In fact, the parents of your `<menupopup>` tags should be `<menu>` tags - then you will get a submenu (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menu#Example)). A `<menuitem>` tag is always a single menu item.

For reference, what happens when you add `<menupopup>` to a `<menuitem>` tag: this tag replaces the auto-generated contents of `<menuitem>`. `<menupopup>` isn't a visual element however so what you get is a menu item without any visible content whatsoever.